# Finding most frequently occuring n-word-pairs (skip-grams) in N text blocks

Tags: algorithm, text-mining, n-gram

Given: N text blocks (unique words inside each block). For arbitrary numbers n and k, how can one find the k most frequent n-word-pairs to appear in the N text blocks?

For n = 1, it is a trivial. We can generate the [term-document matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) (TDM) and sort descending by frequency. For n = 2, we can use the TDM to generate a co-occurrence matrix C = TDM*TDM' and then search for the k biggest values. The index in the matrix tells us which word pairs are most frequent.

How could one generalize this concept for arbitrary n? How can one optimize for computational time? Is there an existing algorithm for this?

I am thankful for any suggestions.

Note: the software I use is MATLAB.